# How to send a message to client from server using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I want to send a message to a client from server.

In my scenario the client is not connected with the server. Is it possible for server to establish a connection with not connected client and establish the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client has to establish the connection. Only then can the server send messages back to the client.